# Python: Error with if-statement

Tags: python, if-statement, compiler-errors

```
start = end
  end = 450
  split = 413

for frameNum in range (start, end):  # frames 0 .. 9
  if frameNum <= split:
    space = makePicture(getMediaPath("space.jpg")) #1229 x 692 pixels 
    rocket = makePicture(getMediaPath("rocket1.png")) #74 x 139 pixels
    copyInto(rocket,space,614,553 - frameNum*2 + 2*start)
    writeFrame (frameNum, directory, space)
y = 553 - 2*split + 2*start   
  if frameNum > split:
    space = makePicture(getMediaPath("space.jpg")) #1229 x 692 pixels 
    rocket = makePicture(getMediaPath("rocketWOflames.jpg")) #74 x 139 pixels
    addOvalFilled (space, 150 + int(30*math.cos(1*frameNum/2)),150 + int(20*math.sin(1*frameNum/2)), 70, 30, red)
    copyInto(rocket,space,614,y)
    writeFrame (frameNum, directory, space)
```

The place at which I am having trouble is "if frameNum > split:"

Here is the error message:

```
Invalid syntax
Your code contains at least one syntax error, meaning it is not legal jython.
The error is on line 94
```

I checked the indentation--it appears to be correct; I tried replacing the if-statement with else--didn't work. Can anyone spot the error?

Comment: looks like a weird indentation error. is the `y = 553 - 2*split + 2*start` actually indented like that or is that a copying error? same as your first 3 lines

Comment: The code you have pasted here has lots of indentation errors

Comment: ...shoot..There were indentation errors...I apologize for the trivial problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I cleaned it up for you.

```
end = 450
start = end
split = 413

for frameNum in range (start, end):  # frames 0 .. 9
    if frameNum <= split:
        space = makePicture(getMediaPath("space.jpg")) #1229 x 692 pixels 
        rocket = makePicture(getMediaPath("rocket1.png")) #74 x 139 pixels
        copyInto(rocket,space,614,553 - frameNum*2 + 2*start)
        writeFrame (frameNum, directory, space)
    y = 553 - 2*split + 2*start   
    if frameNum > split:
        space = makePicture(getMediaPath("space.jpg")) #1229 x 692 pixels 
        rocket = makePicture(getMediaPath("rocketWOflames.jpg")) #74 x 139 pixels
        addOvalFilled (space, 150 + int(30*math.cos(1*frameNum/2)),150 + int(20*math.sin(1*frameNum/2)), 70, 30, red)
        copyInto(rocket,space,614,y)
        writeFrame (frameNum, directory, space)
```